# error when opened for first time, PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I receive an error message when the program is run directly, but when I click the search button it works correctly.

The error message is `Notice: Undefined index no in [...] on line 21` and line 21 is `$no1 = $_POST['no'];`

How do I fix this?

Here is my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Searching </title>
</head>
<body>


<form method="POST" action="out.php">
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>  No </td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="no"> </td>
        <td> <input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT" value="search" > 
        <?php

        include('connect.php');


        $no1 = $_POST['no'];
        $no = strtoupper($no1);
        $query = mysql_query("select no, type, time from park where no = '$no'") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="type" maxlength="30" value= "<?php echo $data['type']; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="time" maxlength="4" value= "<?php echo $data['time']; ?>" //></td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use `$no1 = isset($_POST['no']) ? $_POST['no']: null ;`

Comment: @Baba: or better yet: `empty($_POST['no']) ? null : $_POST['no'];`, and to the OP: know that this code is wide open to injection attacks: don't use `mysql_*` extension anymore (it's being deprecated), switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*` and learn about _prepared statements_

Comment: @Baba : thx, it works **$no1 = isset($_POST['no']) ? $_POST['no']: null ;**

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `empty` will still trigger the Notice.

Comment: @toxalot: no it won't `empty` is the same as doing `!isset($x) || !$x`: check is var is set, and checks for falsy values: _No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false._ [From the docs](http://www.php.net/empty)'s section parameters

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You are correct in that no **Warning** is generated, but a **Notice** is generated for array indexes that aren't set. Note that `isset` works differently in this regard for array indexes as compared to variables.

Comment: @toxalot: Let's assume you're correct and emtpy issues a notice: PHP uses short-circuit evaluation, and since the docs state that `empty` is the same as `!isset($x) || $x == false`, that would imply that checking if a var exists using `isset` issues a notice either way. Feel free to report this bug, but I run my scripts on with my ini set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`, and I don't get notices using `empty`... version 5.4.7 on slackware

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I was **so sure** that `empty($_REQUEST['action'])` was generating a `Notice: Undefined index` in one of my scripts. But now I can't reproduce it. I have since changed servers though and maybe it's a version thing? But if that were the case, my Google search should have turned up something. I guess I was hallucinating that day.

Comment: @toxalot: we've all been there, perhaps you got the notice because your code looked something like `$x = empty($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : null;` or a typo in the POST's key... or you were indeed hammered :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

first check weather `$_POST['no']` is set and not `empty`

```
if(isset($_POST['no']) && !empty(trim($_POST['no']))){
  $no1 = $_POST['no'];
        $no = strtoupper($no1);
        $query = mysql_query("select no, type, time from park where no = '$no'") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

      .
      .
      .


      }
        ?>
```

**Warning:** your code is vulnerable to [**sql injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and `mysql_*` function are deprecated so  use either [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: `mysql_*`  , SQL injection ??? I expect better

Comment: I have tried, but it appears an error message like this : **<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: data in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\search_mysql\search.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />**

Comment: all $data should be in if body

Answer (score 1):

When you first run `$_POST['no']` is not set, but when you select the search button `$_POST['no']` is filled. So in your code you should test whether it is set or not

```
if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error **Undefined index** in your posted image is thrown when an index of an array is not set. The error does in this case mean that the value of input field `no` is not posted (yet) and thus the variable `$_POST['no']` is not set.

You can prevent the error from being issued if you first check if that variable exists. This can be done with the *'magical'* [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

```
if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
    $no1 = $_POST['no'];
}
else {
    $no1 = ...
}
```